# Show percentages in px.sunburst chart without using update traces

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python, exploratory-data-analysis

I have plotted a px.sunburst chart in plotly subplots.

Hence I cannot use:

```
fig.update_traces(textinfo="label+percent parent")
```

I need a way to show the percentages within the px.sunburst() function.

I have already tried

```
fig.update_traces(textinfo="label+percent parent")
```

It doesn't work because the sunburst in a subplot with multiple other charts.

Here is the code snippet:

```
## Pclass and Survived Sunburst
sb3 = px.sunburst(pclass_survived_df, values='count', path=['Pclass', 'Survived'],
                 color_discrete_sequence=[color_1, color_2])
fig.add_trace(sb3.data[0], row=7, col=2)
```

Titanic Dataset

Comment: Please add a full example, and let the person who wants to help solve it with any method.

Comment: You can use `update_traces` and specify that if only applies to one trace. For example, if there is only one sunburst or if there is more than one and you want all of them to have `"label+percent parent"`, you could use: `fig.update_traces(selector = ({'type': 'sunburst'}), textinfo = 'label+percent parent')`